# Docker login to custom Docker registry fails

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

There's a custom Docker registry that I'm trying to login in order to upload my Docker image. I'm able to log in to the same custom Docker registry through web UI. But the same fails using `docker login` command. Let's take `demo.registry.com` as the custom registry that I'm trying to login to. This is what I've tried so far :-

`docker login -u demouser demo.registry.com`

Enter pwd :-

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://demo.registry.com net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Any idea/suggestions on how to login would be useful. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this github issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/611), may be you need to redefine DNS, or your browser have some proxy/VPN, but docker uses native connection with blocked connection to registry.

Also docker can use specific port for connection to registry that blocked by your net administration or something like this.